# writing iOS SDK: no access to client app delegate, want to lock orientation for a particular screen

Tags: ios

XCode: 14
iOS: 16 (supports upto ios12)

i am writing ios sdk, which presents some UI when we call its method. but since its an SDK, i don't have access of client app delegate.

Goal: there are 2 screens (A) and (B). if screen(A) is on let say portrait mode, and user go to screen(B) from screen(A) then even if user rotate device to any other orientation, it should not rotate screen(B).

SDK supports min version ios 12 to 16+.

tried a few methods but none of them worked.
that's why posted a question here.

Shouldautoroate(),
Preferred Orientation () doesn't work.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        
    }
    
    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
    
    override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return .portrait
    }
```

tried above approach but doesn't work.

shows erorr

```
BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: Setting UIDevice.orientation is not supported. Please use UIWindowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(_:)
```

**Update 1**

i am able to implement orientation lock on screen, but its like, it will rotate it for a second, and figure out if it matches or supported orientation or not, if it doesn't match then it will rotate to require orientation.
but all of this takes 1-2 seconds, but i want to lock is completely, in sense that it should not even rotate for a second.

**Update 2**

i am able to implement lock orientation feature in iOS SDK. but that requires an additinal call. i am not sure if its a best way.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
// here .all - indicates current client app supports all orientations.
        return <SDKClassName>.supportedInterfaceOrientations(.all)
    }
```

> supportedInterfaceOrientations() method check if current top viewcontroller is of kind SDKViewController and also checks for current interface orientation and update it to either landscape or portrait depending upon value, if top view controller is not SDKViewController then it returns the original supported interface mask value.

looking for a better solution now.
Thanks.

Comment: my next goal is: if i can achieve same without calling supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window.

Comment: My understanding viewController A is in your main project and viewController B is in your SDK. You are presenting B from A, and B must match A's orientations right ?

Comment: yes @Sreekuttan

Comment: not only it should match but it should not rotate to other orientations also.

Comment: Try my answer below

Comment: @Sreekuttan, i have commented in reply.

Comment: @Sreekuttan, in your answer, you have assumed that FirstViewController supports landscape mode, but since its a client app, it can support any orientations/ all orientations.

Comment: updated the answer try now

Comment: again, FirstViewController is from client app, SDK doesn't have access to it.  inside FirstViewController, i can only call a method to present views. like <sdk_class_name>.showWallet()

Comment: I just added firstViewController to try out, you need to only refer SecondViewController. Add only shouldAutorotate in viewController from your sdk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249194/discussion-between-sreekuttan-and-matrix).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present different UIs for different orientations, for what I understood. The best API IMO is:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3198088-interfaceorientation

```swift
Import UIKit // guess is necessary

// inside your function or class check

UIWindowScene.interfaceOrientation (...)

//Then you have three options to check your environment

// Getting the interface attributes

var traitCollection: UITraitCollection

// The traits that describe the current environment of the scene.

var coordinateSpace: UICoordinateSpace

// The coordinate space occupied by the scene.

var sizeRestrictions: UISceneSizeRestrictions?

from those you can create one UI or another.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue in the past and the problem was ViewController was put into NavigationController.

If so - subclass NavigationController, override same methods that you did in ViewController B, and use it for wrapping ViewController B

```
class CustomNavigationController: NavigationController {

    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }

    override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for ios16.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I’ll try to check this in a day and get back to you as its fairly interesting problem.